# How to make invisible Field Odoo 14

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-14

In register payment wizard , I added 2 fields. I want to make fields invisibles according to 'move_type'

if move_type == 'in_invoice' --> field1 : invisible

if move_type == 'out_invoice' --> field2 : invisible

```
<record id="view_account_payment_register_form_inherit_payment_test" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">account.payment.register.form.inherit.payment.test</field>
  <field name="model">account.payment.register</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_account_payment_register_form"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <xpath expr="//group/field[@name='communication']" position="after">
          <field name="field1"/>
          <field name="field2"/>
       </xpath>
 </field>
</record>
```

How can I do it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `payment_type`, the payment type will be `Send Money` for vendor bills and `Receive Money` for customer invoices.

***Example:***

```
<!-- move_type == in_invoice (Vendor Bill) -> payment_type == outbound (Send Money) -->
<field name="field1" attrs="{'invisible': [('payment_type', '=', 'outbound')]}"/>

<!-- move_type == out_invoice (Customer Invoice) -> payment_type == inbound (Receive Money) -->
<field name="field2"  attrs="{'invisible': [('payment_type', '=', 'inbound')]}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `attrs` attribute.

```
<field name="move_type" invisible="1" /> <!-- you need this for attrs domain work -->
<field name="field1" attrs='{"invisible":[("move_type","=","in_invoice")]}' />
<field name="field2" attrs='{"invisible":[("move_type","=","out_invoice")]}' />
```

You need to have `move_type` in your datamodel for this to work. If not, add it as relative field. You can do it like this in your wizard code

```
    move_type = fields.String(related="account_move.move_type")
```

Comment: I haven't move_type , How can I add it as relative it in 'account.payment.register' model?

Comment: What model has that move_type you want to use and how that model is related to your account.payment.register? And to be exact that move_type has to be in the view to use it as a condition for attrs. But to get that field into a view you need to have it in a data model.

Comment: move_type is from standard Odoo : when creating a Vender Bill or Customer Invoice, there is a wizard when clicking on register payement .Here I added 2 fields . I Want to show /hide fields in wiard according to move_type(in_invoice/out_invoice) , meaning If it 's  Vendre Bill: in wizard if register payment showing only field2 , and for Customer Invoice showing only field1.